# Colocar aspas no início e fim de cada número

Tags: php

Preciso colocar aspas no inicio e fim de cada número.

Exemplo:

tenho a seguinte sequencia:

```
$seq = "123,456,789";
```

o resultado teria que ficar assim

```
$seq = "'123','456','789'";
```

Comment: E como tentou fazer? Qual foi o resultado obtido?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode também fazer um Explode, Map e depois Implode pra transformar, vou enviar abaixo o exemplo:

```
 $myNumbers = "123,456,778";
 $myNumbersExploded = explode(",", $myNumbers);
 $myNumbersWithNewCaracter = array_map(function($v){ return "'".$v."'"; }, $myNumbersExploded);
 $myNumbers = implode(",", $myNumbersWithNewCaracter);

 var_dump($myNumbers);
```

[veja rodando no ideone](https://ideone.com/38b1Bi)

Saída abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: acertei a variavel no var_dump e aproveitei coloquei seu exemplo no ideone

Comment: Muito obrigado @LeoCaracciolo!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode concatenar a aspa simples no início e no final da string e substituir a 
vírgula ","  por " ',' "  (aspa simples + vírgula + aspa simples) utilizando o substr_replace do php.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr-replace.php.

Qualquer dúvida poste ai pra gente ver.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar `explode()`

```
function colocaAspas($n){ return "'".$n."'"; }

$seq = "123,456,789";
$seq = array_map('colocaAspas', explode(',', $seq));

var_dump($seq);
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma de fazer:
`$seq = "123,456,789";` 
`$explode_seq = explode(',', $seq);` 
`$n = array();` 
`foreach ($explode_seq as $num){` 
     `$n[] = "'" . $num . "'";` 
`}` 
`$result = implode(" , ", $n);` 
`echo $result;`